# Googled, and failed: Looking for a really good video on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I Hope you can understand my difficulty in finding a really good tutorial video for WordPress. Not sure why, but I'm having a hard time finding some basic stuff in WordPress; like how to create a custom template using CSS. I know CSS, and Html just fine. But instead of just googling every little thing I come across ( i would not follow the trend of asking for help for every little detail) I am looking for a complete and quality video tutorial in WordPress, not just for myself, but for my people.

Since beginning training in Java I've learned it's best to learn broader rather than getting hung up on details, which I can research later, and go back to with references. If I understand the whole concept then when I want to do something specific, I at least know where to start looking on my own. With WordPress I don't have a broad view, and that's what I'm aiming for. Please don't just Google search 'Good WordPress Tutorial Video' and post the first decent looking link. I am looking for recommendations through experience. If you know of a good Tutorial Video Series on WordPress please then consider replying. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress.org not in video but excellent documentation available!

Comment: Thank you. I'm really not sure what the point of wordpress even is. Is it's a WYSIWYG? or is it just a template that you could use as is, but will need to type your own edits? I'm just clueless to the point of wordpress.

Comment: It is a content management system that helps you to ensure that everything appears on the site in the same layout (template) and facilitates the editing process. In addition a broad range of plugins facilitate a lot of other things.

Comment: Thanks Jochem this answers my question fully! Although I had to read it twice to understand it. Tired, not your fault. I hope to learn much more, please keep an eye for me.